# Java / LibGDX: Get custom object properties on box2D collision

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm setting up checkpoints in my game, and want the player to get the color it's supposed to be every time it respawns. Otherwise, the player dies immediately.

I've tried this piece of code, inside my contact listener (checking for contact between fixture a(player) and fixture b(checkpoint)):

```
MapObjects objects = play.getTileMap().getLayers().get("checkpoints").getObjects();

for (MapObject object : objects) {
    if (object.getProperties().containsKey("Color")) {
        int color = object.getProperties().get("Color", Integer.class);
        Gdx.app.log("Respawn color", Integer.toString(color));
        game.setRespawnColor(color); 
    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't get the property "Color" from the checkpoint the player collides with, but from the last checkpoint it finds.

A workaround would be to add one checkpoint layer for each color (red_checkpoint) for example, but that would add what feels like a lot of unnecessary code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UserData to your Fixtures and Bodies which you can read if it collides.

When you create the Bodies of your Checkpoint add a UserData to the Fixture and Body:

```
Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
body.setUserData(Checkpoint.COLOR_RED); //Set the Color of the Checkpoint as Body UserData

FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
fixture.setUserData(Type.CHECKPOINT); //Set the Type of the fixture to detect if it a Checkpoint
```

Checkpoint enum can look like this:

```
public enum Checkpoint {
    COLOR_RED(1),
    COLOR_GREEN(2);

    public final color;
    Checkpoint(int colorValue){
        color = colorValue;
    }
}
```

Then in your collision listener, you can get these UserData:

```
Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

Checkpoint collidedCheckpoint = null;
if(fixA.getUserData == Type.CHECKPOINT){ //Check if fixA is a Checkpoint
    collidedCheckpoint = ((Checkpoint)fixA.getBody().getUserData());
} else if(fixB.getUserData == Type.CHECKPOINT){ //Check if fixB is a Checkpoint
    collidedCheckpoint = ((Checkpoint)fixB.getBody().getUserData());
}
if(collidedCheckpoint != null){
    //Get the color of the Checkpoint by saving a int in the enum or something else
    int color = collidedCheckpoint.color; // 1
} else {
    //Not with a Checkpoint collided
}
```